# Improve video quality

Tags: video

```
BitmapSource bs = null, bs2 = null, bs3 = null, bs4 = null;
        BitmapData bitmapData = new BitmapData(), bitmapData2 = new BitmapData(), bitmapData3 = new BitmapData(), bitmapData4 = new BitmapData();
        int imageWidth = bitmap.Width / 3;
        int imageHeight =bitmap.Height;
        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        var size = (rect.Width * rect.Height) * 4;
        try
        {
            bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
                    rect,
                    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            bitmapData2 = bitmap2.LockBits(
                 rect,
                 ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            bitmapData3 = bitmap3.LockBits(
                  rect,
                  ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            bs = BitmapSource.Create(
                   bitmap.Width,
                   bitmap.Height,
                   bitmap.HorizontalResolution,
                   bitmap.VerticalResolution,
                   PixelFormats.Bgra32,
                   null,
                   bitmapData.Scan0,
                   size,
                   bitmapData.Stride);

            bs2 = BitmapSource.Create(
              bitmap2.Width,
                   bitmap2.Height,
               bitmap2.HorizontalResolution,
               bitmap2.VerticalResolution,
               PixelFormats.Bgra32,
               null,
               bitmapData2.Scan0,
               size,
               bitmapData2.Stride);

            bs3 = BitmapSource.Create(
                bitmap3.Width,
                   bitmap3.Height,
                 bitmap3.HorizontalResolution,
                 bitmap3.VerticalResolution,
                 PixelFormats.Bgra32,
                 null,
                 bitmapData3.Scan0,
                 size,
                 bitmapData3.Stride);
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            bitmap2.UnlockBits(bitmapData2);
            bitmap3.UnlockBits(bitmapData3);
        }

        //imageWidth = bitmap.Width / 2;
        //imageHeight = bitmap.Height / 2;
        // Draws the images into a DrawingVisual component
        System.Windows.Size size1 = new System.Windows.Size(imageWidth * 2, imageHeight * 2);
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            drawingContext.DrawImage(bs, new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
            drawingContext.DrawImage(bs2, new Rect(imageWidth, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
            drawingContext.DrawImage(bs3, new Rect(imageWidth * 2, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
            //drawingContext.DrawImage(bs3, new Rect(0, imageHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight));
            //drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(), null, new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(), size1));
        }
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        // Converts the Visual (DrawingVisual) into a BitmapSource
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(imageWidth*3, imageHeight, 100,100, PixelFormats.Default);//PixelFormats.Pbgra32
        //RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(imageWidth * 3, imageHeight, 110, 110, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);//PixelFormats.Pbgra32
        bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
        try
        {
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
            // Saves the image into a file using the encoder
            using (Stream stream = File.Create(Path.Combine(ApplicationCache.Instance().DefaultImageFolder, fileName + Constants.ImageCapture.DEFAULT_IMAGE_EXTENSION)))
            {                    
                encoder.Save(stream);
            }
            GC.Collect();
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EX.Message);
        }
```

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: Please read **[How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. What's your JPEG's quality setting? Also it might be better to consider using FFmpeg to encode the bitmap data directly into video frames. Check if your programming language allows you to connect to an external program (are you on Windows?). This way you could start FFmpeg as a **process** where you can then pass your bitmap data bytes each time to make a new frame in video.